# Delete Facebook App with Real Time updates from a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I tried enabling the Facebook real-time updates with an app for one of my Facebook pages.

> curl
>   https://graph.facebook.com/#{page_id}/tabs?access_token=#{page_access_token}

It worked fine and I can get post updates properly.

But when I tried to delete the app from the page to stop these updates using the below API,

> curl -X DELETE \
>        -d "" \
>           https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/tabs/app_{app-id}

I am getting the below response:

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "**(#100) Tab is not installed or not removable: app_{app-id}**", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 100
>   } }

How do I solve this issue? How do I remove my real-time updates enabled app from my page?

I found this bug report in Facebook. Its very old and no one seems to have done anything about it.

> https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/503381706394259/

Comment: I hope facebook developer will resolve this problem.
see this link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259
He mentioned "We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed next Tuesday" i.e MAY 20. Let see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the follwing endpoint instead:

> DELETE /{app-id}/subscriptions HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.facebook.com
>
> object=page

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions#delete